# Are tenses in this quotation sequenced correctly?

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past, indirect-speech, sequence-of-tenses

One of the examples listed in *Oxford Dictionary for Learners* caught my attention. Regularly I can explain the grammar of all examples listed there, but not this time.
The quotation is:

> As a child he had thought he could fly, if he willed it enough.

When I try to reproduce the sentence, I start with the conditional

> If you will it enough, you can fly.

It's zero conditional, because I indicatively state what I believe is true. Then I proceed to direct speech

> He thought, ‘I can fly, if I will it enough.’

Then to indirect

> He thought he  could fly, if he willed it enough.

Adding the last element I end up with final sentence, which lacks the word ‘had.’

> As a child he thought he could fly, if he willed it enough.

How have this happened? I see no way how there could be past perfect instead of simple past. The presence of time also makes simple past more favorable. So I look forward to hear about how this very sentence is actually perceived by native speakers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that you used the wrong tense when you proceeded to direct speech.

Rather than working from

> He thought, ‘I can fly, if I will it enough.’

You should have worked from

> He had thought, ‘I can fly, if I will it enough.’

As for why the past perfect would be used in this sentence: one of the uses of the past perfect is to indicate that an event or state occurred before the timeframe of surrounding sentences that use the simple past as the narrative tense.

For example:

> Adam **was** a disillusioned man. [*simple past*] As a child he **had thought** he could fly, if he willed it enough. [*shifted backward to past perfect because this sentence is further in the past than the preceding one*] But as an adult, he **knew** it was impossible to fly no matter how hard he willed it. [*shifted forward to simple past again to indicate we're returning to the main narrative timeframe*]

If you used the present as the main narrative tense, you would be able to just use the simple past to indicate a shift in viewpoint to earlier on:

> Adam **is** a disillusioned man. [*simple present*] As a child he **thought** he could fly, if he willed it enough. [*shifted backward to past tense because this sentence is further in the past than the preceding one*] But as an adult, he **knows** it is impossible to fly no matter how hard he wills it. [*shifted forward to simple present again to indicate we're returning to the main narrative timeframe*]

However, most narration in English uses the past tense as the main tense rather than the present.

For this sentence, you can infer from the use of the pronoun "he" without any visible antecedent that there must be some kind of surrounding context that is not shown.

If you have reason to believe that the context is present-tense, the simple past would be more appropriate.  For example, if you're asked a question like "What is an interesting fact about Adam," it would be correct to use the following sentence in the simple past as your response:

> As a child he thought he could fly, if he willed it enough.

(In this context, the past perfect would sound wrong.)

But without context, you can't conclude one way or another which form is more correct.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough reply. So past perfect only makes sense when there is some context? The context in your explanation is ongoing narration, and relations between sentences over time would perfectly justify past perfect. However, will it still be right to think that when there is no context and when all we work is this bare sentence, the usage of past perfect is wrong? I learned that if that's time that is important (today, a year ago, when I was a child), one should stick to simple; and when the result, then perfect. This one sentence suggests is clearly about time, not the result.

Comment: @Demis: I would say you can infer that there must be some surrounding context that is not shown from the use of the pronoun "he" without any visible antecedent.

Answer (score 0):

1) As a child he *had thought* he could fly, if he willed it enough. But then he realized, he never would. [NOTE: but then he //realized// he never //would//. The next sentence shows that the *past perfect activity PRECEDES the activity in the simple past*.

2) As a child he thought he could fly, if he willed it enough. But then, he realized, he never would.

Both sentences are grammatically correct. But they have different timelines.

In 1), the speaker would be uttering or writing that sentence in the past, not the present. In 2), the speaker is speaking now about a time in the past that is over in relation to the present.

That said, in both sentences, *the action of willing applies once as finish thought to either realized or had realized*.